# Cannot clone git repository because of SSL error

Tags: git, ssl

I am using git version 2.19.0 and I defined my .gitconfig as follows:

```
[http]
    sslVerify = false
```

But I keep having the same error:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/project
  Cloning into 'project'...
  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/project/': SSL connect error
```

How should I config git to no longer have this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by replacing https://github.com/project/ by git://github.com/project/

... but it is clearly a hack.